# using babel-register with dynamically added exports results to undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am having a file, where I create exports dynamically like:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import config from '../config';
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database.name, config.database.user, config.database.password, {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  host: config.database.host,
  logging: false,
  define: {
    underscored: true
  }
});
const db = {
  sequelize,
  Sequelize
};

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== 'index.js');
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ('associate' in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

export default db;
```

With babel 5 register hook this kind of code was working just fine. Now I was about to upgrade to babel 6 and so I used `require('babel-register')`. It is working fine, except that if I want to call the dynamic added attributes like

```
import { sequelize } from './the_above_file';
```

then the variable `sequelize` is always `undefined`.
But if I call

```
import db from './the_above_file';
```

then `db.sequelize` has a value.

Is there a way to fix it or do I have to avoid dynamic values in the export;

Comment: The only way to get dynamic named exports is to create the module file dynamically as a part of your build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import { sequelize } from './the_above_file';` should have never worked since you don't have a **named** export with that name. You only have a default export which is an object. Properties of the default export are not the same as having named export.

That was considered a bug in Babel  5 and Babel 6 fixed it.

You can do

```
import db from './the_above_file';
const { sequelize } = db;
```

to extract the property `sequelize` of your default export.